# How do I login to a site I am viewing on my localhost?

Tags: authentication, localhost

I am editing a site while viewing on my localhost:3000. There are certain things I need to login to view, but my login credentials (which are accurate on the actual site) are not accepted on my local. The error I get is "Authentication Error." How do I login to my local?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: We haven't got a clue how your site's code (which you haven't shared with us) tries to authenticate you.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new and didn't write the original code. What would you need to see exactly? It's a very big project file.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it can help someone else... I needed to add a ".env.local" file with various keys and IDs from Stripe and others. That allowed me to log in to my localhost with no problems.

Comment: please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked.